# Android BlutoothChat, making class instance available across other activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-bluetooth

I'm messing around with one of the Android Samples Bluetooth chat, im relatively new to Android so I'm here to get users opinions, In the main activity class and instance of the class "BluetoothChatService mChatService" is created this does all the controlling of the bluetooth connectivity,
       Now I have created a new Activity that launches a page of buttons, these buttons will send certain hardcoded messages depending on which one is pressed, aseen as "mChatService" has been initiated and is handling the connection I would like to make this class instance available in my newly created Activity so I can send messages straight away,

What is the best practices to make this available?, I have read about Serializing the class (which wont work in this instance) so I can pass it in with the Intent, and also singletons?

Can anyone advice what way this SHOULD be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Singleton is fine, as long as it doesnt become dirty. :)

Comment: If you use a singleton you have to implement thread-safe code.  I would use an intent since it was made for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make your class [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) you could use [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and do intent.putExtra() when sending and intent.getExtras().getParelable() on the receiving end.

Passing a reference to a Bluetooth class might get tricky. You would probably be better handling the message sending back in the original activity.

Comment: I think you may be right, i may rethink my design have my "mChatService" instance on the ACtivity that will be using it most.

Comment: How about this... create a module(make it static) that handles the communication and mark the methods in the module with "synchronized" to keep it thread-safe. I wouldn't just make a static mChatService for free access by any activity though.  I would encapsulate it.

Comment: Will look into this, to be honest im not sure what a module it yet :D

Comment: Just a class really :) nothing special